# Apply noConflict to jQuery load content script

Tags: jquery

Would anyone be able to help me apply a no conflict to my load content script? So far I've tried to add the following to the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var $j = jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

I also replaced all instances of '$' with '$j' in the following script but it simply doesn't run anymore when I have made these changes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  



$('#nav li a').click(function(){  

var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';  
$('#content').fadeOut('400',loadContent);  
$('#load').remove();  
$('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');  
$('#load').fadeIn('normal');  
function loadContent() {  
    $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent()); 
}  
function showNewContent() {  
    $('#content').fadeIn('400',hideLoader());  
}   
function hideLoader() {  
    $('#load').fadeOut('normal');  
}  

fleXenv.initByClass("flexcroll"); 

initLytebox();

return false;  
});     
});
```

I've read all the jquery documentation on this, but I'm afraid its quite a bit beyond my current jquery level. Any help would be much appreciated, Im at a real low at the moment.

Thanks Mike

Comment: You could use an anonymous function and keep your references....

Answer (score 1):

Use an anonymous function and wrap your existing jQuery code:

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FdNn9/)**

```
$.noConflict();

(function($){
    // original code here, with $ being a jQuery reference
    // (but only within this code block)
})(jQuery);

// this will fail
$('body').css('background-color','green'); // $ is not a function
```

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks for the fast response. I've just tried pasting my above code into the area that you suggested and it wont run. Should I remove the code from its own file and paste it into the header of my site?

Comment: @user: I guess it depends on how you're using it. Place the whole file contents within the anonymous function within the file itself. So "myfile.js" should begin with `(function($){` and end with `}(jQuery);` but be loaded after the jQuery file and the `<script>$.noConflict</script>` line of your header.